# NLTK and SCIPY are not executing my python script

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, scipy, nltk, importerror

Hello i have installed `scipy` and `NLTK` packages to explore machine learning using python.

I have installed all the necessary dependencies and followed the install procedure given in the `NLTK` and `scipy` website

My script is executing fine in python shell but when i save it in a python script and execute in the terminal i get the following output ....

```
puneet@puneet-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ python token.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "token.py", line 4, in <module>
    import nltk 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.util import ngrams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 31, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/home/puneet/Desktop/token.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text
```

This is my script:

```
import nltk 
import scipy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
#vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
test_set = ("The sun in the sky is bright.",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.")

print vectorizer

cv = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['sun', 'blue', 'bright'])
cv.fit_transform(['The sun in the sky is bright.', 'We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.', 'The sun is bright.', 'nine days old']).toarray()
```

Could someone suggest a workaround to execute my script. I think it's got to do with the PYTHONPATH variable... i think!! :D but i'am not able to modify it! please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your file with `something.py` because there is one more file in python2.7 package(/usr/lib/python2.7/token.py) with name token.py and there is a name collision.

If you are getting the below error:

```
NameError: name 'N_TOKENS' is not defined
```

Then login as a root user. Change the `line 30` in file name `tokenize.py`

```
from token import * --> from token2 import *
```

Also it requires to rename the file(/usr/lib/python2.7/token.py):

```
token.py --> token2.py
```

From the traces it seems to be you don't have `sklearn` installed.

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

I have just modified you script adding and removing some of the lines.

```
import nltk 
import scipy
import sklearn         #added this line
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
test_set = ("The sun in the sky is bright.",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.")
#removed the line which was present
cv = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['sun', 'blue', 'bright'])
output = cv.fit_transform(['The sun in the sky is bright.', 'We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.', 'The sun is bright.', 'nine days old']).toarray()
print output
```

It compiled fine with out any errors.

Output:

```
manjunath@manjunath-virtual-michine:~/Desktop $ python my_test.py
[[1,0,1]
 [2,0,1]
 [1,0,1]
 [0,0,0]]
[[1,0,1]
 [2,0,1]
 [1,0,1]
 [0,0,0]]
manjunath@manjunath-virtual-michine:~/Desktop $
```

Comment: Thanks manjunath that was indeed helpful...Yes skleran was not installed.. I got it fixed though i installed  virtualenv and was able to install the packages and its dependencies... then installled them correctly in my system